# How can I fix my two column data display when entering correct item.firstName & item.lastName data?

Tags: html, grid, row, card

I have a small problem with displaying data in two columns

I have a small problem with displaying data in two columns, namely if I enter data from my finger, everything is displayed correctly, but if I enter correct data of the type item.firstName & item.lastName, everything breaks down...

Am I missing a div or class?

`[ ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKx3.png) [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3J07.png) [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMCG.png)`